# problema con el cacheo de this

Tags: javascript

Buenas estoy el siguiente código que lo he sacado de esta [página](http://www.etnassoft.com/2012/01/12/el-valor-de-this-en-javascript-como-manejarlo-correctamente/) este ejemplo en concreto :

```
var myApp = function(){
     var that = this;
     var name = "World";
     var sayHello = function(){
         console.log( 'Hello, ' + that.name );
 }; 
sayHello(); 
};
myApp();
```

Se supone que cuando hago la llamada a la función `this` se refiere al propio objeto por tanto al guardar en la variable `that`, se guarda el valor del objeto y luego en consola `that` tiene acceso a `name`, pero cuando depuro `this` sigue apuntando al objeto `window`. Si alguien me puede decir que pasa y porque. Se lo agradecería.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que una función pueda tener acceso a su propio ámbito utilizando `this`, tienes que inicializarla utilizando el operador `new`. Esto porque cuando ejecutas una funcion de forma normal, el ámbito por defecto es `Window` que es lo que pasa en tu caso.

Tambien es bueno notar que en tu ejemplo tienes el error de que estas declarado la variable `name` privada, para que `this` pueda encontrarla, tienes que agregarla al objeto como `this.nombrePropiedad`:

```js
var myApp = function(){
     var that = this;

     // var name no define la propiedad en el ambito this 
     // mientras que this.name si la define en ella.
     this.name = "World";
     var sayHello = function(){
         console.log( 'Hello, ' + that.name );
 }; 
sayHello(); 
};
new myApp();
```

Comment: Gracias por responder pero tengo una duda, myApp no es el nombre de una función? con el new dices que seria objeto. Porque es lo veía igual a que poner "function myApp {}" Si me lo podrías aclarar, gracias.

Comment: A ver si entendi. Quieres saber la diferencia entre las formas de declarar una funcion `myApp(){}` y `var myApp = function(){}`?

Comment: Bueno para comenzar soy estudiante entonces creo que tenia claro eso, pero es que he visto el operador new y me confundido un poco y bueno he visto en páginas que una función también la declaran así , poniendo una variable y la función anónima seguida, y leí por ahí que era lo mismo a que ponerlo de forma normal.

Comment: Sí, es lo mismo. En javascript es posible guardar la referencia de una funcion y pasarla por todo tu programa como un objeto cualquiera, a eso se llama [First class Citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen). De ahi que sea posible guardar la referencia de la funcion en una variable como si fuera un string o un boleano.

Comment: Vale osea que esa variable que guardar la referencia de la función puede instanciarse sin problema, y las variable declaradas dentro se acceden a el como atributos. Gracias por la aclaración.